# running maven build on jenkins slave not working

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I am trying to setup a maven project in jenkins via freestyle option. I have set manage jenkins->configure system to set maven downlaod automatic. But, when I run the project on the slave where there is no maven isntall, it does not automatically download maven on slave and install as i expected. am i thinking something wrong here?

This is what I have done :
1. Manage jenkins-> configure system-> maven install automatically
2. create a new job and select freestyle project
3. in the build step:
scp pom file from master to slave machine
run maven from slave using this pom file

Here there is no maven installed in slave. But, i though because of step 1, it will automatically download maven on slave and install before running the build .

Comment: _maven project in jenkins via freestyle option_ You either u maven style project or free style.  Could you clarify your question, please.

Comment: i have edited my question with details. please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build step you need to "Invoke top-level Maven targets", select the Maven version you configured and trigger the job again.

if the installation you added is by extracting *zip and not from Apache you have a **"Label"** field that is co-related to the Label of the node you're running on. I always use Tools label on my slaves, so just make sure you have this label configured in the node itself.

Comment: My question is do i need to setup maven on the slave myself or it will download and setup automatically as I thought it would?

Comment: You don't need to manage anything on the slave. as I said in my answer - it all depends how you configured your maven installation in Jenkins management. if it's automatic installation from Apache you don't need to do anything (you might see issues with proxy settings or timeout while downloading the installation). if you chose to extract a zip file as the method of installation there is a field called "label" you need to fill, and there should be a "Label" field in the node configuration page, and you need to make sure it has it as well. I hope it's clearer. 
Good luck!